# How do I use Material-UI icons in React Native

Tags: react-native, material-ui, expo

I'm using react native and I am trying to use Material-UI icons.

I have npm installed both @material-ui and @material-ui/icons.

I have included:

```
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
```

To the top and I have the icon in my return as:

```
<AddIcon />
```

However I'm getting the error

> Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component 'path'
> must be a function (received 'undefined'). Make sure to start
> component names with a capital letter.

Removing the `<AddIcon/>` removes the error but then obviously the icon doesn't show.

I'm using react-native and expo. I'm not using an emulator or android studio. I'm coding this project in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library installed by default in expo
Change Ionicons with the name of icon you want & always check docs !
https://docs.expo.io/guides/icons/

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```